# Binding generic data to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, binding

I am trying to create a generic DataGridView that can be generated based on a list of any data type.
For that, I created a user control with generic type T, and when I am adding an instance of it to another form, I initialize it with the class I want the DataGridView to be populated.
I also created a method that sets the generic table bindings, based on the data list that I feed it.

```
public partial class UCTabelaDinamica<T> : UserControl
{
    private BindingSource TableSource { get; set; }
    private BindingList<T> TableList { get; set; }

    public UCTabelaDinamica()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetTableBindings(IList<T> tableData)
    {
        TableList = new BindingList<T>(tableData);
        TableSource = new BindingSource(TableList, null);

        dtTabela.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dtTabela.DataSource = TableSource;
    }
}
```

Now, to use this user control in the form, I instantiate it like this:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ucTabelaDinamica1 = new DataGridViewBuilderImproved.UCTabelaDinamica<Person>();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // ucTabelaDinamica1
        // 
        this.ucTabelaDinamica1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.ucTabelaDinamica1.Name = "ucTabelaDinamica1";
        this.ucTabelaDinamica1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(475, 337);
        this.ucTabelaDinamica1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(499, 361);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ucTabelaDinamica1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private UCTabelaDinamica<Person> ucTabelaDinamica1;
```

After that, I populate the table:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person
            {
                name = "Joao",
                age = 18
            },
            new Person
            {
                name = "Pedro",
                age = 21
            }
        };

        ucTabelaDinamica1.SetTableBindings(people);
    }
```

The problem is the table is showing in the form, but no data is showing, or columns are created, and I cannot understand why. I have searched and seen different topics about this, saying to use BindingList, and then BindingSource, but nothing seems to be working. Little help?

**UPDATE:**

As @Jimi suggested, I moved the generic T type to the SetTableBindings function, but it still doesn't show me any data in the table

```
public partial class UCTabelaDinamica : UserControl
{
    private BindingSource TableSource { get; set; }

    public UCTabelaDinamica()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetTableBindings<T>(IList<T> tableData)
    {
        TableSource = new BindingSource(new BindingList<T>(tableData), null);

        dtTabela.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dtTabela.DataSource = TableSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have not attached the `Form_Load` handler to the `Load` event of the form. At list we cannot see it inside the expected method `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: Off-topic, but when `BindingSource`, you don't need to use a `BindingList<T>`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I confirm that the event is properly set, and I see it firing in debugging

Comment: @RezaAghaei I thought BindingSource needed to have a BindingList associated

Comment: The BindingSource class handles an `IList` on its own. You don't need this: `UCTabelaDinamica<T>`. It will also prevent your UC from being added to the Controls in the ToolBox (the `<T>` type is unknown). You could modify your `SetTableBindings` in `public void SetTableBindings<T>(IList<T> tableData)`. If you want to use a `BindingList` (not required in this specific context), you can declare it in-place: `BindingList<T> tableList = new BindingList<T>(tableData);`, removing the related Property. Also, you have modified the Form's `InitializeComponent()` method manually. Don't do that.

Comment: @Jimi You are totally right, that was a workaround that I did so that T type was recognized, but I forgot that I could define it in the function in itself. I made the corrections that you suggested, including in the InitializeComponent() that I had incorrectly changed. It is still not working.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what was happening.

My Person class had the following:

```
 public class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
}
```

I changed it to:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And it is now fully working.

Comment: I had the same problem, took me hours to figure out. :D